# How to deal with very large integers?

Tags: c, input, io, int, scanf

If I have to store and do an operation on integers in the wide range of [1, 10^50000]. How can I do them? How can I store such large integers values first of all? And, how can I perform basic operations on them subsequently?

Comment: thats larger than all the atoms in the universe. why would you need that?

Comment: maybe he/she is doing calculations for all the atoms in the universe.

Comment: The largest Mersenne prime has over 17 million digits.  OP's range wouldn't touch that.

Comment: You need about 166097 bits (20763 bytes) to represent a number that size. =)

Comment: @John: Do you mean the largest **known** Mersenne prime, or have you proven there are no more?

Comment: @Eric Yes, I did mean largest known Mersenne prime.  It was too late to edit my comment when I realized the error, though.  o_O

Answer (score 3):

There are specialized libraries for arbitrary precision that will help you with this.  One I had success with is [GMP](http://gmplib.org/).

Comment: but seriously why would one need this?

Comment: I don't care.  OP asked, I answered.

Comment: but why would anyone need this?

Comment: Prime calculation, maybe. Or perhaps for working out problems on Project Euler.  It's not difficult to come up with a number of reasons why this would be helpful.

Comment: @АртёмЦарионов Just because *you* don't need it, doesn't mean it's useless.

Comment: @paddy: АртёмЦарионов did not write that it was useless, they asked why one would need it.